# Combobox no firemonkey sem utilizar FDQuery

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal

Possuo um combobox de estados em meu cadastro, onde faço conexão via livebindings com um FDMemTable para gravar os dados no banco.
Como eu poderia pegar o item index do item selecionado no combo?

O único binding bidirecional que achei foi o SelectedValue, só que ele retorna a string do item e eu preciso do index.

Não quero carregar meu combo a partir de um FDQuery ou FDMemTable

Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
ACombo.Items.AddObject(GetPropValue(FListaCombo.Items[I], FCampoDescricao), FListaCombo.Items[I]);
```

Utilizo o RAD Studio XE 10.2

**Editado:**

Obs.: Meu projeto é em firemonkey (FMX)

O ItemIndex gera um link unidirecional

[image: O itemindex gera um link unidirecional]

Já o SelectedValue gera um link bidirecional, só que só retorna o texto e eu quero o index (ou id)

[image: Já o SelectedValue gera um link bidirecional, só que só retorna o texto e eu quero o index (ou id)]

Answer (score 1):

Se ele retorna a String do Item, utilize a função nativa da classe `TStrings`.

Ex: `ComboBoxX.Items.IndexOf('o_que_ele_retornou_string');`

Ver documentação interna da IDE: **TStrings - > IndexOf**.

Obs. Se a String aparecer mais de uma vez na Lista, ele retornara índice da primeira!

**Edit.**

Para ligação manual, deve se ter em mente que o "binding" não traz todas propriedades, deve selecionar o componente na janela do `LiveBindingis Design` e pressionar *CTRL+N* e checar a propriedade desejada!

Comment: Não sei se me expliquei bem, mas eu gostaria de pegar o index utilizando o livebinds

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro tudo bem, verifique a edição da resposta.

Comment: Esse procedimento do CTRL+N eu já conhecia, o problema é que nem com esse comando eu consegui encontrar uma propriedade que seja bidirecional que me retorne o index do item selecionado

Comment: A `ItemIndex` não funciona? qual a versão do Delphi?

Comment: Bom toda vez que linko com o ItemIndex é gerado um binding uniderecional , só que quero um bidirecional.

Estou utilizando o RAD Studio 10.2.2 Tokyo

Comment: verifique a edição da pergunta